# In Excel, how can I use VBA to dynamically merge cells with same value?

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I am creating an excel for project management and on the Gantt part, it would be good to have both days and weeknum as information.

[image]

As you can see on the picture, the scroll bar on top makes the table change, so the merge would also have to change as the numbers move around.

I have not tried much, because I just can't possibly think of a way of doing this automatically. I want the cells to merge and unmerge because the results will change.

This is what I expect to happen:

[image]

If needed, I can show how the scroll works to make it visually easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastColumn As Long, StartPoint As Long, EndPoint As Long, i As Long, y As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Find the last column of row 1
         LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'Set StartPoint
        StartPoint = 1

        'Loop row 1
        For i = 1 To LastColumn

            If i = StartPoint Then

                For y = i + 1 To LastColumn

                    If .Cells(1, i).Value <> .Cells(1, y).Value Then

                        EndPoint = y - 1
                        Exit For

                    End If

                Next y

                Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                    With .Range(.Cells(1, StartPoint), Cells(1, EndPoint))
                        .Merge
                        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                    End With

                Application.DisplayAlerts = True

                StartPoint = y
                EndPoint = 0

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I use.

```
Sub MergeSame()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim First As Range
    Dim Last As Range

    Set rng = Selection

    If rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To rng.Columns.Count + 1
        If rng.Cells(1, i).Value <> PreviousValue Then
            If Not (First Is Nothing) Then
                Set Last = rng.Cells(1, i - 1)
                Range(First, Last).Merge
            End If
            Set First = rng.Cells(1, i)
            PreviousValue = rng.Cells(1, i).Value
        Else
            rng.Cells(1, i).Clear
        End If

        rng.Cells(1, i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    Next i

End Sub
```